# How to verify textField input?

Tags: java, verify

I know this shouldn't be too difficult but my searching hasn't led to anything useful yet. All I want to do is make sure the user inputs a positive integer into a textField. I've tried:

```
public class myInputVerifier extends InputVerifier {
    @Override
    public boolean verify(JComponent jc) {
        String text = ((jTextFieldMTU) jc).getText();
        //Validate input here, like check int by try to parse it using Integer.parseInt(text), and return true or false

        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
}
```

So in my main code I want to use this to display "OK" if successful and "Enter a positive number" if not successful.

Can someone point me in the right direction please? Thanks!

Comment: Let me help break this down for you: 1) capture the content of the text field 2) parse the String to produce an int 3) check whether the int is >= 0. Use your Google Fu and please delete this question -- it's off topic.

Comment: @MarsAtomic: I wouldn't say that it's off topic, as it's a valid question, but perhaps it was not strongly researched prior to asking.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels how are you?

Comment: @MarsAtomic I've been researching this for a couple days now and I only post here if I truly need some help. Like I said I know this can't be too difficult but I'm still relatively new to Java so some things are still a little fuzzy.

Comment: @getlost: hello Madhawa. I am fine and sincerely hope that you are too.

Comment: @shoota so your question is answered now ..are u still have problem ?

Comment: @shoota In hindsight, I was too hasty in calling it off-topic, but there is a "close" category for questions unlikely to be of use to others, and I'd say your question falls squarely in this group. In the future, your research should include a search of Stack Overflow itself. The answer to the issue at the heart of your post has existed for years. Try to expend a bit more effort next time -- your future coworkers will thank you.

Comment: @getlost I was able to use Yellos' answer to get my code working, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You could use a try-catch block to check if the input is an integer:

```
try {
    int i = Integer.parseInt(input);
    // input is a valid integer
}
catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    // input is not a valid integer
}
```

Comment: Yep 1+. Then return true from below the parsing (after checking that its > 0) and false from the catch block so that the verify method behaves appropriately.

Comment: @Yellos Thanks for the answer, I will give it a try. I guess the thing I'm not sure about is how to implement this since it needs to go in it's own method and then that method is called elsewhere in the program. I'll mess with it for a bit, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

String has a matches method you can use with regular expressions to see if the contents match a particular pattern. The regular expression for positive integers is ^[1-9]\d*$ so you can use it like this...

```
boolean matches = text.matches("^[1-9]\d*$");

if(matches){
   //Do something if it is valid
}else{
   //Do something if it is not
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you tell me what "^[1-9]\d*$" does or at least is called so I can research it. I've seen this a few times in my research but I haven't found any useful documentation on it (probably because I don't know what it's called in order to google it).

Comment: [Here is a good reference to regular expression characters in Java.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) 

It basically reads "Match any string that begins with a digit from 1-9, followed by any number of valid digits, and ends with a digit."

Regular expressions are a way of representing a search pattern as a string. If you're unfamiliar with them, there are some great video tutorials on youtube that explain them in general.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use try catch.
Catch the NumberFormatException.
In this way you check if the text can be parsed to an integer. If not you can display an error message to the user.
After that you can us an if else statement to check if the number is positive if not positive you can give the user an error message. I suggest you research try catch if you don't know it.